# Expect script for postfix installation as it opens with prompt window

Tags: shell, automation, expect

my script: postfix.exp

`#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn sudo apt-get install -y postfix
expect 'Preconfiguring packages ...\r'
send "\t"
send "\r"
send "\r"
expect eof`

After executing following command:

> $ expect postfix.exp
>
> Output which i get: 
>   Reading packages 0%
>
> and then it exits

please help me with automating the installation of postfix.
I get 2 prompt windows which asks for following input:

> 1. For first window i need to select from the options and my option is the default one i.e no internet
> 2. For second window just press enter.

Issue can be reproduced with running postfix installation command:

> sudo apt-get install -y postfix

And prompt windows which i get:
[first prompt window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyYI1.png)    [second prompt window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQalU.png)

Comment: `printf "\t\n\n" | sudo apt-get install -y .. ` ?

Comment: that's hold true when i am selecting default option, what would be the sol for if have to select not the default option. if possible solve it using Expect script.